# How can i add a Tool Buttons for Mayavi pipeline options

Tags: python, pyqt4, mayavi, qtoolbutton

Here is my mayavi program,in that mayavi pipeline have several options i.e like volume and Colors and legends, i want to add those options to right side of my plot as a tool buttons, because directly i want to change my setting on my plot i don't want to click again mayavi pipeline.So please tell me how to add that options like a tool buttons.Thank you in advance.
This is my code:
[image]

```
import scipy as np
from mayavi import mlab


x,y = np.mgrid[-3:3:100j, -3:3:100j]

a = 0.3

a0 = 0.2

r1=np.sqrt((x-a)**2 + y**2)

values = np.sinc(-r1/a0)



mlab.surf(values, warp_scale='auto')

mlab.outline()

mlab.axes()
# mlab.test_contour3d()
mlab.show()
```